# Disable all child elements using angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created a directive that disable all of the selected child elements like this :

```
app.directive('noeDisable', function () {
        var linkFunction = function (scope, element, attributes) {
            scope.text = attributes["=noeDisable"];
            if (scope.text == 'true') {
                $(element).find('input,button,a').attr("disabled", true);
            }
        };
        return {
            link: linkFunction

        };
    });
```

and it work well for this example: `<div noe-disable="true"> ... </div>`. but the problem is some of the child elements load later, for example after ajax call or when I have another angularjs directive inside parent element that add some child elements to its parent, so they wont be disabled !!!
How can I deal with this problem ?

Comment: Nice question. Are you targeting old browsers?
There are serveral solutions to this, but the nicest ones are ever-green only.

Comment: @SanderElias I use modern browsers like google chrome version 37

Comment: Good! you can use an mutationObsever then. One question left,
The thing you add to your directive, are those direct children to this directive, or is there a (number of) layers in between?

Comment: Add **$watch** on the variable that gets updated after the ajax call and execute the disable routine.

Comment: @SanderElias, Tnx for your help, I just look for direct nested children and there can be many nested layer and ...

Comment: @MRP, Ok, do you need me to write you a sample? I don't have the time right now, but probably later today or tomorrow I will.

Comment: @SanderElias tnx, I will wait for your help.

Comment: @ArunGhosh I will try your idea

Comment: you can use fieldset to disable all child fields in that fieldset

Comment: TNX @entre I used fieldset and I was simple and good solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use fieldset.

Wrap all your fields in fieldset and use ng-disabled like:

```
<fieldset ng-disabled="shouldDisabled"> 
         ... inputs ...
</fieldset>
```

It will automatically disable all inputs inside the fieldset.

Comment: that's an elegant solution :)

Comment: Doesn't work on IE, works on Edge but no version of IE

Comment: However, while it works for angular material inputs it does not work for angular material buttons.

Comment: `<fieldset [disabed]="myConditoin"> ... ` worked for me

Comment: @Yomi1984 That's because you're using Angular 2+

Answer (score 2):

Had a spare (couple off) minutes!

[Here is the plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/gd0erzwouZIpXgjVTIJH?p=preview) showcasing the mutationObserver.

the crux is in this line:

```
observer.observe(element[0], config);
```

witch subscribe to all the dom updates of the element.
I ditched the dependency on jQuery, while I was at it ;)